# Python 2.7/Opencv3.0: Number of centroids is incorrect using cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats.

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, opencv, opencv3.0

I used `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats`in Python 2.7 to find out centroids of three blobs in a binary image. (Image is given below `In code it is img3`).
[image]

In this image, three white bolbs are present so number of centroids should be three only but python shows 8 centroids values of which are

```
[[ 307.08579803   95.31441513]
 [ 511.51325364  141.06288981]
 [ 259.          112.5       ]
 [ 296.07169811  129.18490566]
 [ 276.          140.5       ]
 [ 225.19643047  237.16190375]
 [ 189.21212121  271.6969697 ]
 [ 187.58333333  285.83333333]]
```

Area of each bolbs are given in last column

```
[[     0      0    640    480 286024]
 [   260     65    100     68   3753]
 [   454     84    105    118   7696]
 [   259    112      1      2      2]
 [   277    117     34     23    265]
 [   276    140      1      2      2]
 [   168    173    114    128   9413]
 [   186    268      8      8     33]
 [   186    284      5      4     12]]
```

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import timeit
from skimage import morphology, measure

img = cv2.imread('left180.png')

lower_white = np.array([150,150,150], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([255,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)

binimg = cv2.inRange(img, lower_white, upper_white)
cv2.imshow('res',binimg)

binimg[binimg!=0] = 255
# flood fill background to find inner holes
holes = binimg.copy()
retval, image, mask, rect = cv2.floodFill(holes, None, (0, 0), 255)
# invert holes mask, bitwise or with img fill in holes
holes = cv2.bitwise_not(holes)
#cv2.imshow('holes',holes)
filled_holes = cv2.bitwise_or(binimg, holes)
cv2.imshow('filled holes', filled_holes)

imglab = morphology.label(filled_holes)
cv2.imshow('label',imglab)
cleaned = morphology.remove_small_objects(imglab, min_size=1264, connectivity=4)
#np.savetxt('cleaned.csv',cleaned,fmt='%.18g',delimiter=',')
cv2.imshow('clea',cleaned)
img3 = np.zeros((imglab.shape))

img3[cleaned > 0] = 255
img3= np.uint8(img3)  #### here conversion of array into uint8 data conversion is important
                      ### else cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats will show error.
#np.savetxt('img3.csv',img3,fmt='%.18g',delimiter=',')
nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img3, connectivity=4)
sizes = stats[1:, -1];
#nb_components = nb_components - 1
cv2.imshow("centroid", img3)
centroids1 = centroids[1:nb_components]
print(centroids1)
print(stats)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Why is this problem happening? I want to get the centroids of blobs which area is greater than say 1000 pixels. How to do that?

Comment: Use `connectivity=8`. Currently the big blobs have some small pieces connected but they're only connected by diagonal pixels (as far as I can tell, some may be a full pixel of separation).

Comment: I tried with `connectivity=8` but the result is same.

Comment: Then there is indeed 8 components as the labels say, and they are disconnected (you can see some small blobs that look *almost* connected to the big blobs but aren't). You uploaded a `jpg` but you should save as a `png` for others to try. Also `stats[:, -1]` will indeed give you the sizes, so if you want the corresponding centroids just get the indices of the areas that are greater than your threshold size. For e.g. `centroids[np.where(stats[:, -1] > threshold)]`. You can ignore the first return value here if you want to ignore the centroid of the bg label.

Comment: You could `dilate()` the image by a small amount to grow the blobs so they merge, or you could do a morphological closing to grow the blobs so they merge, and then shrink them back down again by the same amount. See more [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html).

Comment: I saved above binary image img3 in excel by using `np.savetxt('img3.csv',img3,fmt='%.18g',delimiter=',')` and by seeing in it, this show three lables namely 2, 14 and 40 only. Also, in  code I used `morphology.remove_small_objects(imglab, min_size=1264, connectivity=8)` which will remove small lablels having area less than 1264 even then my centroids shows values of area of 33,12 etc. Why so?

Comment: It's my result with different methods. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjWSH.png

Comment: Read the [docs for `remove_small_objects()`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects). The connectivity from `skimage` is different than that for OpenCV. You want `connectivity=2` for `remove_small_objects`. See the little ASCII diagram [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.morphology.html#label).

Comment: @Silencer Can you please post your code here to do the same thing so that in future I can check centroids like this.